# Upgrade JFrog Artifactory Professional 5.4.5 to latest available 6.17

Tags: devops, artifactory

I am new to JFrog and I have been assigned a task to upgrade JFrog Artifactory pro from 5.4.5 to latest available i.e. 6.17. Currently, it is installed using a zip file on a Linux server and using the default Derby database.

What is the best approach I can take?

1. Can I directly upgrade from my existing version to the latest or do I have to upgrade to some interim version and then upgrade to the latest?
2. Since I also have to migrate existing Artifactory to a new server(VM). Can I directly install the latest 6.17 version of Artifactory and restore the data from old server?
3. Should I first migrate existing artifactory to the new server and then migrate?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly upgrade from Artifactory version 5.4.5 --> 6.17.0. Full steps on how to upgrade your instance can be found on our Artifactory user guide here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Upgrading+Artifactory#UpgradingArtifactory-UpgradingtotheLatestVersion. This section of our user guide will provide step by step instructions on how to upgrade based on installation type. There are also recommendations on backing up your instance before upgrading on this page as well.

Comment: HI Mari, Thanks for your reply. I am also migrating our repo to a different server. So do I need to first migrate and then upgrade or I can just load the back up to the latest installed version(6.17) of repo?